# Checkbox Filter with Multiple Condition using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<div id="c_b" class="checkbox-elemet">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="nri" id="nri" name="status[]"><label for="nri">NRI</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="resident" value="resident" name="status[]"><label for="resident">Resident</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="salaried" value="salaried" name="status[]"><label for="salaried">Salaried</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="self_employed" value="self_employed" name="status[]"><label for="self_employed">Self</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="govt_employee" value="govt_employee" name="status[]"><label for="govt_employee">Govt.</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="others" value="others" name="status[]"><label for="others">Others</label></div>
</div>
```

Following condtions sholud fulfill for enabling each checkboxes,

1. NRI,Resident should enable
   initially, all other are disabled
2. NRI checked : Only Salaried and
   Others enable
3. NRI and Salaried checked : No other
   Enable
4. Resident checked : Salaried, Govt, Other, Self should
   enable
5. Resident and Salaried checked :
   Govt. and Other enable
6. Resident and Self checked : No other
   Enable

Anybody can help me with a simple solution.

Comment: Here is my script : http://jsfiddle.net/kyathi/mFPNa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be **like** this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //1. NRI,Resident should enable initially, all other are disabled
     disableAll(); $("#nri", "#resident").attr("disabled", false);
     //Req 2
     $("#c_b :checkbox").change(function(){
        //2. NRI checked : Only Salaried and Others enable 
        if(isChecked("#nri")){ disableAll(); enable("#salaried, #others"); }
        //3. NRI and Salaried checked : No other Enable
        if(isChecked("#nri") && isChecked("#salaried")){ disableAll(); enable("#nri, #salaried"); }
        //4. Resident checked : All child should enable
        //what is child?
        //5. Resident and Salaried checked : Govt. and Other enable 
        if(isChecked("#resident") && isChecked("#salaried")){ enable("#govt_employee, #others"); }
        // 6. Resident and Self checked : No other Enable
        if(isChecked("#resident") && isChecked("#self_employed")){ disableAll(); enable("#resident, #self_employed"); }
     });
  });
  function disableAll(){
     $("#c_b :checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  }      
  function isChecked(id){
     return $(id).is(":checked");
  }
  function enable(sel){
     $(sel).attr("disabled", false);
  }
```

I didn't understand your fourth requirement.
Hope this helps